# AngularJS, Retrict Selection in Input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, google-geocoding-api

Im using Google Geocoding to search for address and load a list with possible locations so the user can input his/her country/city in a form.

For that I followed the example in:

[Angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

The Typehead Section

But, even after the list is loaded, the user can write and input whatever they want.

Can I restrict the input only to one of the items in the list?? (instead of just free typing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeahead-editable: false` might do this for you. I am not in a position to test and confirm it. However, I recommend checking out [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) as this may be more appropriate for what you are doing.

Comment: can't believe I didn't saw that